# ListView item doesn't show text when icon enable in API 8

Tags: android, listview

I have a very strange bug with `ListView` items **in API 8 device**. I have a very simple layout for file dialog:

[image: file dialog picture]

It works fine on device with API 15. But HTC Desire with API 8 show this dialog as:

[image]

So I can see text only for elements (files) without folder icons. **I can see folder text only when scroll the list!**

When I hide icons with `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` the text appears everywhere.

Some code of my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (viewBinder == null)
    {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
    else
    {
        View view = convertView == null
                ? viewBinder.inflateView(position, mResource, mInflater, parent)
                : convertView;

        viewBinder.setViewValue(view, position, getItem(position));
        return view;
    }
}


        public View inflateView(final int position, final int defResource,
                final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final boolean checkable =
                    isCheckable((T) getListAdapter().getItem(position));
            final View view = inflater.inflate(checkable ?
                                               R.layout.filepicker_listitem_checkable :
                                               R.layout.filepicker_listitem_dir,
                    parent, false);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.icon = view.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);

            viewHolder.text =
                    (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            if (checkable) {
                viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckedTextView) view
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            } else {
                viewHolder.checkbox = null;
            }
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

            return view;
        }

public void setViewValue(final View view, final int position,
                final T data) {
            if (view.getTag() == null) {
                return;
            }

            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).text.setText(getName(data));

            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).icon.setVisibility(isDir(position, data) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

            if (((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox != null) {
                ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox
                        .setChecked(checkedItems.get(position));
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
filepicker_listitem_checkable.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_filepickertheme">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_collection_light"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<CheckedTextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:checked="false"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

filepicker_listitem_dir.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_filepickertheme">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_collections_collection_light"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/name"/>
```

Comment: I think it's more important to see your layout files

Comment: layouts for items are quite simple. i have updated the question

Comment: I assume textView color playing an important role here. try to set different color on TextView.

Comment: no:( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9_PokrJ2SoCUGlueV81YngzY28/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides I fixed this bug! Just need to add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to `TextView` and `CheckedTextView` elements in list items layouts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the first example the text is white with a black background, and in the second example there is a white background with no tex . My guess is that the text is there, but it is white, so it is invisible. Try changing the `TextView` color to black, or whatever color you want, and see if that makes a difference. Try adding the following to your `TextView` layout: `android:textColor="@color/black"`

Comment: and why it works on API 15? also i've set color to red and the result is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9_PokrJ2SoCUGlueV81YngzY28/view